# Javascript: Looping an object with TypeError property undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object called `xs` that store name

```
xs = [
    {name: "Peter"},
    {name: "Doe"},
    {name: "Parker"},
    {name: "John"}
];
```

and i have a function setEmptyStr that return empty string if variable is undefined

```
function setEmptyStr(v) {
  if(typeof v !== 'undefined'){
    return v;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

I try to looping my array of object (with more length than the array it self), my array length is 4, i try 5. and i dont wanna use array.length;

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(setEmptyStr(xs[i].name));
}
```

the 4 names are return successful because it is not undefined. But the 5th is return

> TypeError property 'name' is undefined.

```
>>Peter
>>Doe
>>Parker
>>John
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I want the 5th is return an empty string. How can i do this? Is there is an error in my code?

```
>>Peter
>>Doe
>>Parker
>>John
>>""
```

Comment: No there's no error in your code, actually  `arr[5]` will be `undefined` that's why you got this error.

Comment: `xs[i]` is the thing that is undefined, not `xs[i].name`.

Comment: i have try it and it return Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. i want my arr[5] return an empty string, not and undefined. How can i do this?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, of i see i understand now. thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```js
xs = [
    {name: "Peter"},
    {name: "Doe"},
    {name: "Parker"},
    {name: "John"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(setEmptyStr(xs[i] && xs[i].name));
}

function setEmptyStr(v) {
  if (typeof v !== 'undefined') {
    return v;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Testing `xs[i]` first prevents an error from trying to access a property of `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It Works ^_^

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: I wrote an explanation. It apparently disappeared when I created the stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no errors in your code, but it's unsafe to loop over an array with an index which is higher than its length, it will throw this kind of error.

In your code  `xs[4]` will be `undefined` that's why you got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

So you just need to catch and avoid this error like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(xs[i])
        console.log(setEmptyStr(xs[i].name));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Yeah i now understand what my false

Answer (score 0):

No *name* is not undefined:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

So actually *xs[i]* is undefined. Your loop runs 5 times, but you only have 4 elems. You might use *.length* to be shure:

```
for(var i=0;i<xs.length;i++)
```

Comment: The OP states "i dont wanna use array.length [sic]"

Comment: questioner said, dont wanna use array.length you forgot to notice that

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(setEmptyStr(xs[i].name));
}
```

You are trying to send `name` of individual array element without checking whether its available or not. in your 5 th entry you dont have anything so it return `undefined`. because your array length is 4.

so check whether you have `object` before send like this,

```
if(xs[i]) {
  setEmptyStr(xs[i].name)
}
```

Comment: thank you very musch, it worked to ^_^.  Use if statement before setEmptyStr.