# Dynamic web page is showing uncaught error on retrieving objects attributes . How to do it properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created 2 JavaScript files to display data dynamically in HTML. One JavaScript file data.js has an array of objects (lets say catalog) and another JavaScript file (function.js) has a function which loads those objects, then creates HTML elements and display items (catalog) on HTML page.

console is showing me an uncaught error on name, price (attributes) `articleName.innerText = catalog[i].name;`error` I am not getting why this error is occurring?

Please guide me how to resolve this.

[image: error details]

```js
//function.js
function func() {
  var articles = document.getElementById("content");
  var catalog = catalogArray;
  for (var i = 0; i <= catalog.length; i++) {
    var article = document.createElement("div");
    article.setAttribute("class", "addClass class2 class3");
    var articleName = document.createElement("h2");
    articleName.setAttribute("class", "heading class2 class3");
    articleName.innerText = catalog[i].name;
    article.appendChild(articleName);
    var articleDecs = document.createElement("div");
    articleDecs.setAttribute("class", "border class2 class3");
    articleDecs.innerText = catalog[i].desc;
    article.appendChild(articleDecs);
    var articlePrice = document.createElement("div");
    articlePrice.setAttribute("class", "border class2 class3");
    articlePrice.innerText = catalog[i].price + " Dh";
    article.appendChild(articlePrice);
    articles.appendChild(article);
  }
}

// data.js
var catalogArray = [{
    code: 100,
    name: "Learn JS",
    desc: "To make your web paged dynamic",
    price: 150,
    image: "./images/100Tshirt.jpg"
  },
  {
    code: 101,
    name: "T Shirt",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.",
    price: 0,
    image: "./images/101Tshirt.jpg"
  },

  {
    code: 102,
    name: "T Shirt 2",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.",
    price: 0,
    image: "./images/102Tshirt.jpg"
  }
];
```

```css
.addClass {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: grey;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: 2px solid yellow;
}

.heading {
  color: green;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.imgclass {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="func()">
  <section id="content">
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Change `catalog.length` to `catalog.length-1` or `i < catalog.length` since arrays are zero based.

Comment: Please show errors as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Looping an object with TypeError property undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464112/javascript-looping-an-object-with-typeerror-property-undefined)

Comment: @imvain2 or change `<=` to `< catalog.length` then no need for `catalog.length-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate too many times and need to account for arrays being zero based:

`for (var i = 0; i <= catalog.length; i++) {`

This should be:

`for (var i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++) {`

Demo:

```js
//function.js
// data.js
var catalogArray = [{
    code: 100,
    name: "Learn JS",
    desc: "To make your web paged dynamic",
    price: 150,
    image: "./images/100Tshirt.jpg"
  },
  {
    code: 101,
    name: "T Shirt",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.",
    price: 0,
    image: "./images/101Tshirt.jpg"
  },

  {
    code: 102,
    name: "T Shirt 2",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.",
    price: 0,
    image: "./images/102Tshirt.jpg"
  }
];

function func() {
  var articles = document.getElementById("content");
  var catalog = catalogArray;
  for (var i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++) {
    console.info(catalog[i]);
  
    var article = document.createElement("div");
    article.setAttribute("class", "addClass class2 class3");
    var articleName = document.createElement("h2");
    articleName.setAttribute("class", "heading class2 class3");
    articleName.innerText = catalog[i].name;
    article.appendChild(articleName);
    var articleDecs = document.createElement("div");
    articleDecs.setAttribute("class", "border class2 class3");
    articleDecs.innerText = catalog[i].desc;
    article.appendChild(articleDecs);
    var articlePrice = document.createElement("div");
    articlePrice.setAttribute("class", "border class2 class3");
    articlePrice.innerText = catalog[i].price + " Dh";
    article.appendChild(articlePrice);
    articles.appendChild(article);
  }
}
```

```css
.addClass {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: grey;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: 2px solid yellow;
}

.heading {
  color: green;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.imgclass {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="func()">
  <section id="content">
  </section>

</body>
```